# How save instance of File in Node.js/Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

I need to save file recieved from frontend/postman. For example .txt file:
[image]

After that, on backend, I get the file like this:

```
const { body, files } = ctx.request;
```

"ctx" it is object refers to Strapi API.
This file looks like

```
console.log(files.client)
```

It is instance of File:

```
File {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  size: 7,
  path: 'C:\\Users\\vvv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_552c6e1cb7710c6c490533566b7be1d1',
  name: '111.txt',
  type: 'text/plain',
  hash: null,
  lastModifiedDate: 2022-04-20T06:41:53.462Z,
  _writeStream: WriteStream {
    fd: null,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\vvv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_552c6e1cb7710c6c490533566b7be1d1',
    flags: 'w',
    mode: 438,
    start: undefined,
    pos: undefined,
    bytesWritten: 7,
    closed: true,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: true,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: true,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: true,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    [Symbol(kFs)]: {
      appendFile: [Function: appendFile],
      appendFileSync: [Function: appendFileSync],
      access: [Function: access],
      accessSync: [Function: accessSync],
      chown: [Function: chown],
      chownSync: [Function: chownSync],
      chmod: [Function: chmod],
      chmodSync: [Function: chmodSync],
      close: [Function: close],
      closeSync: [Function: closeSync],
      copyFile: [Function: copyFile],
      copyFileSync: [Function: copyFileSync],
      cp: [Function: cp],
      cpSync: [Function: cpSync],
      createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream],
      createWriteStream: [Function: createWriteStream],
      exists: [Function: exists],
      existsSync: [Function: existsSync],
      fchown: [Function: fchown],
      fchownSync: [Function: fchownSync],
      fchmod: [Function: fchmod],
      fchmodSync: [Function: fchmodSync],
      fdatasync: [Function: fdatasync],
      fdatasyncSync: [Function: fdatasyncSync],
      fstat: [Function: fstat],
      fstatSync: [Function: fstatSync],
      fsync: [Function: fsync],
      fsyncSync: [Function: fsyncSync],
      ftruncate: [Function: ftruncate],
      ftruncateSync: [Function: ftruncateSync],
      futimes: [Function: futimes],
      futimesSync: [Function: futimesSync],
      lchown: [Function: lchown],
      lchownSync: [Function: lchownSync],
      lchmod: undefined,
      lchmodSync: undefined,
      link: [Function: link],
      linkSync: [Function: linkSync],
      lstat: [Function: lstat],
      lstatSync: [Function: lstatSync],
      lutimes: [Function: lutimes],
      lutimesSync: [Function: lutimesSync],
      mkdir: [Function: mkdir],
      mkdirSync: [Function: mkdirSync],
      mkdtemp: [Function: mkdtemp],
      mkdtempSync: [Function: mkdtempSync],
      open: [Function: open],
      openSync: [Function: openSync],
      opendir: [Function: opendir],
      opendirSync: [Function: opendirSync],
      readdir: [Function: readdir],
      readdirSync: [Function: readdirSync],
      read: [Function: read],
      readSync: [Function: readSync],
      readv: [Function: readv],
      readvSync: [Function: readvSync],
      readFile: [Function: readFile],
      readFileSync: [Function: readFileSync],
      readlink: [Function: readlink],
      readlinkSync: [Function: readlinkSync],
      realpath: [Function],
      realpathSync: [Function],
      rename: [Function: rename],
      renameSync: [Function: renameSync],
      rm: [Function: rm],
      rmSync: [Function: rmSync],
      rmdir: [Function: rmdir],
      rmdirSync: [Function: rmdirSync],
      stat: [Function: stat],
      statSync: [Function: statSync],
      symlink: [Function: symlink],
      symlinkSync: [Function: symlinkSync],
      truncate: [Function: truncate],
      truncateSync: [Function: truncateSync],
      unwatchFile: [Function: unwatchFile],
      unlink: [Function: unlink],
      unlinkSync: [Function: unlinkSync],
      utimes: [Function: utimes],
      utimesSync: [Function: utimesSync],
      watch: [Function: watch],
      watchFile: [Function: watchFile],
      writeFile: [Function: writeFile],
      writeFileSync: [Function: writeFileSync],
      write: [Function: write],
      writeSync: [Function: writeSync],
      writev: [Function: writev],
      writevSync: [Function: writevSync],
      Dir: [class Dir],
      Dirent: [class Dirent],
      Stats: [Function: Stats],
      ReadStream: [Getter/Setter],
      WriteStream: [Getter/Setter],
      FileReadStream: [Getter/Setter],
      FileWriteStream: [Getter/Setter],
      _toUnixTimestamp: [Function: toUnixTimestamp],
      F_OK: 0,
      R_OK: 4,
      W_OK: 2,
      X_OK: 1,
      constants: [Object: null prototype],
      promises: [Getter]
    },
    [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

How save it on server? I was trying to do it via `fs.writeFile` and `fs.createWriteStream`:

```
      fs.writeFile(filePath, files.client, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
      });
```

OR

```
      let writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      writeableStream.write(files.client);
```

But everytime I got an error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of File
```

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of File
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself. File already downladed on server, we need just move it from one folder to another. Path of temporary folder is contained in the File object. Maybe it will be useful to someone:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const oldPath = 'C:\\Users\\vvv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_552c6e1cb7710c6c490533566b7be1d1'
const newPath = 'new/path/file.txt'

fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
})
```